# how to use sed to extract a floating number

Tags: file, sed, insert, floating-point, numbers

I need to read a floating number from file A, located next to a constant1 as follows

```
constA \t 3.1415; //some comments
```

I have tried with, but do not know how to remove rest of things after the desired number

```
#value=$(sed -En 's/constA[[:blank:]]+//p' fileA)
```

Thus the command is reading

```
3.1415; //some comments
```

I would need just

```
3.1415
```

DONE: It is working with the following line code

```
value=$(sed -En 's/constA[[:blank:]]+//p' fileA | sed 's/;.*//')
```

Comment: `sed -En 's/^\bconstA\b[[:blank:]]+([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$/\1/p'`

Comment: value=$(sed -En 's/constA[[:blank:]]+//p' fileA | sed 's/;.*//')

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
value="$(sed -En 's/constA[[:blank:]]+([0-9][0-9.]*).*/\1/p' <<< "$s")"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/OJfBjS)

**Details**

- `-En` - `E` enables the POSIX ERE syntax and `n` suppresses default line output
- `constA[[:blank:]]+([0-9][0-9.]*).*` pattern matches:

  - `constA` - a substring
  - `[[:blank:]]+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace
  - `([0-9][0-9.]*)` - group 1: a digit and then any 0+ dots or digits
  - `.*` - the rest of the string.

`\1` will keep the Group 1 value in the result.

Comment: I'd suggest to include `-` (or even `-+`) in the first digit group to handle possibly signed values. With regard to compatility, it seems that the `+` quantifier is not as portable as `{1,}`, what do you think ? Well at least GNU sed matches `+` literally in ERE + POSIX compatibility mode.

Comment: It would be `'s/constA[[:blank:]]+([-+]?[0-9][0-9.]*).*/\1/p'` since it is POSIX ERE.

Comment: yup, even better :)